# Four Evenly-Spaced Table Boxes

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create four evenly-spaced `<table>` cells but for some reason, I am having a little difficulty doing this (even though I have set certain widths for them).

An example can be seen below, where the second cell appears larger than the others:

[image]

```
<tr>
    <td style="width: 100%; padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="20" border="0" colspan="12" align="center">
        <table style="width: 600px; border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid orange;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="20" border="0" colspan="12" align="center">
            <tbody cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" colspan="12" align="center" style="width: 100%;" width="100%">
                <tr cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" colspan="12" align="center" style="width: 100%;" width="100%">
                    <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="148" style="width: 148px; color: #1F1F1F; text-align: center; border: 1px solid orange; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana; font-size: 8px; letter-spacing: 1.5px; text-transform: uppercase;" >
                        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff.jpg&text=Icon" alt="Bullhorn Icon" width="50" height="50" /><br />
                        <p style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana; font-size: 10px; color: #1F1F1F; text-align: center;">Dolorla ti <br />amet silio</p>
                    </td>
                    <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="148" style="width: 148px; color: #1F1F1F; text-align: center; border: 1px solid orange; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana; font-size: 8px; letter-spacing: 1.5px; text-transform: uppercase;" >
                        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff.jpg&text=Icon" alt="Lab Icon" width="50" height="50" /><br />
                        <p style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana; font-size: 10px; color: #1F1F1F; text-align: center;">Adipiscing <br />consecteture</p>
                    </td>
                    <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="148" style="width: 148px; color: #1F1F1F; text-align: center; border: 1px solid orange; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana; font-size: 8px; letter-spacing: 1.5px; text-transform: uppercase;" >
                        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff.jpg&text=Icon" alt="Atom Icon" width="50" height="50" /><br />
                        <p style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana; font-size: 10px; color: #1F1F1F; text-align: center;">Facili elit <br />torem</p>
                    </td>
                    <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="148" style="width: 148px; color: #1F1F1F; text-align: center; border: 1px solid orange; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana; font-size: 8px; letter-spacing: 1.5px; text-transform: uppercase;" >
                        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff.jpg&text=Icon" alt="File Icon" width="50" height="50" /><br />
                        <p style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana; font-size: 10px; color: #1F1F1F; text-align: center;">Ipsum sit <br />sepida colt</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Js4x/)

How do I create four evenly-spaced table cells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the table-layout propertie.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#fixed-table-layout

In your case:

```
<table style="width: 600px; border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid orange;table-layout:fixed;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="20" border="0" colspan="12" align="center">
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3Js4x/3/)**

Answer (score 2):

As you will notice, when you inspect the parsed content in some devoloper tools, like in Chrome, your `<td>`'s  `width: 148px` is overruled, and replaced with a computed width like `103.8546546px` and so on. Simply add

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

to your CSS or as inline style., and you will get what you want.

forked fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/CaVpC/**